# Shortest Job First for Multiple Queues

Tags: java, eclipse, process, operating-system, scheduling

Currently, I have a program which simulates a shortest job first strategy for a set of processes. However, my task is to make it for multi-priority level queues. So a queue for HIGH, MILD, LOW: HIGH = 1, MILD = 2, LOW = 3. The original code works fine and now I am stuck with trying to implement it for the 3 separate process queues. I have managed to add the correct processes into each queue but there's as far as I got to. 
The problem is, how do I apply the SJF strategy to each queue

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TEST
{
    List<Process> processList;
    List<Process> highPriorityQueue;
    List<Process> mildPriorityQueue;
    List<Process> lowPriorityQueue;
    List<Process> finalProcessList;
    private int count;
    private int timeQuantum;
    int j=0;
    private int ganntP[];
    private int ganntT[];

    private int totalWaitingTime=0;
    private int totalTurnAroundTime=0;

    private float avgWatingTime=0;
    private float avgTurnaroundTime=0;
    TEST(List<Process> processList)
    {
        count=processList.size();
        this.timeQuantum=timeQuantum;
        this.processList=new ArrayList<Process>();
        this.highPriorityQueue=new ArrayList<Process>();
        this.mildPriorityQueue=new ArrayList<Process>();
        this.lowPriorityQueue=new ArrayList<Process>();
        this.finalProcessList = new ArrayList<Process>();
        ganntT=new int[200];
        ganntP=new int[200];        

        for(Process p : processList)
        {
            if(p.getPriority()==1)
                this.highPriorityQueue.add(new Process(p.getProcessId(), p.getArrivalTime(), p.getBurstTime(),p.getPriority()));
            else if(p.getPriority()==2)
                this.mildPriorityQueue.add(new Process(p.getProcessId(), p.getArrivalTime(), p.getBurstTime(),p.getPriority()));
            else if(p.getPriority()==3)
                this.lowPriorityQueue.add(new Process(p.getProcessId(), p.getArrivalTime(), p.getBurstTime(),p.getPriority()));
        }


        Collections.sort(highPriorityQueue, Process.BY_ARRIVAL_TIME);
        Collections.sort(highPriorityQueue, Process.BY_BURST_TIME);
        Collections.sort(mildPriorityQueue, Process.BY_ARRIVAL_TIME);
        Collections.sort(mildPriorityQueue, Process.BY_BURST_TIME);
        Collections.sort(lowPriorityQueue, Process.BY_ARRIVAL_TIME);
        Collections.sort(lowPriorityQueue, Process.BY_BURST_TIME);

        // CREATE NEW QUEUE WITH COMBINED PRIORITIES IN ORDER
        // SEE WHAT PROBLEM IS
        // CHECK SJF WHY NOT WORKING
        //finalProcessList.addAll(highPriorityQueue);
        //finalProcessList.addAll(mildPriorityQueue);
        //finalProcessList.addAll(lowPriorityQueue);

    }

    /*public void simulate()
    {
        int currentTime=0;
        int remainingProcess=count; 
        while (remainingProcess > 0)
        {
            int min=1000;
            int index=-1;
            Process current = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            {
                current = processList.get(i);

                if (current.getRemainingTime() > 0 && current.getBurstTime()<min &&current.getArrivalTime()<=currentTime )
                {   
                    index=i;
                    min=current.getBurstTime();
                }   
            }
            if(index==-1)
            {   currentTime++;
                continue;
            }
            current = processList.get(index);
            if (current.getStartTime()==-1) 
            {
                current.setStartTime(currentTime);
            }

            ganntP[j]=current.getProcessId();
            ganntT[j]=currentTime;
            j++;

            current.setRemainingTime(0);
            current.setEndTime(currentTime +current.getBurstTime());
            currentTime+=current.getBurstTime();
            remainingProcess--;


        }
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {   
            Process current=processList.get(i);
            current.setWaitingTime(current.getEndTime()-current.getBurstTime()-current.getArrivalTime());
            current.setTurnaroundTime(current.getEndTime()  - current.getArrivalTime());

            totalWaitingTime+=current.getWaitingTime();
            totalTurnAroundTime+=current.getTurnaroundTime();
        }
        avgWatingTime=(float)totalWaitingTime/count;
        avgTurnaroundTime=(float)totalTurnAroundTime/count;

    }*/

    public void printResult()
    {
        Collections.sort(this.processList, Process.BY_PROCESSID);
        System.out.println("Simulation result of TEST ");
        System.out.println("ProcessID | ArrivalTime | BurstTime | Priority | StartTime | EndTime| WaitingTime | TurnAroundTime");
        System.out.println("PId ArrivalT BurstT Priority  StartT   EndT  WaitingT TurnAroundT");
        for(Process p : processList)
        {
            System.out.println(p);  

        }
        System.out.println("Average Waiting Time of Multilevel "+avgWatingTime);
        System.out.println("Average TurnAround Time of Multilevel "+avgTurnaroundTime);

        System.out.println("HIGH PRIORITY");
        System.out.println("PId ArrivalT BurstT Priority  StartT   EndT  WaitingT TurnAroundT");
        for(Process p : highPriorityQueue)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        System.out.println("MILD PRIORITY");
        System.out.println("PId ArrivalT BurstT Priority  StartT   EndT  WaitingT TurnAroundT");
        for(Process p : mildPriorityQueue)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        System.out.println("LOW PRIORITY");
        System.out.println("PId ArrivalT BurstT Priority  StartT   EndT  WaitingT TurnAroundT");
        for(Process p : lowPriorityQueue)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Time "+ganntT[i]+" Process "+ganntP[i]);    

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("LIST COMBINE TEST");
        System.out.println("PId ArrivalT BurstT Priority  StartT   EndT  WaitingT TurnAroundT");
        for(Process p : finalProcessList)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

As you'll see the simulate method is commented out due to it being for the SJF strategy, here is where I need to change it to be able to work for all 3 queues I've created.

EDIT:
In my brief it states I need to use shortest job first strategy for multi priority level queues - so my goal is to apply sjf to each queue, then find a way to avoid starvation to low/mild priorities

My final goal being:  A scheudler which has multiple queues for each priority - each implementing shortest job first and a way to avoid starvation to low/mild priorities and avoid long wait time for long burst time processes

Comment: You might want to explain what you already have done, what you want to make "exactly" and what is not working. See how to create a [mcve]. By the way, I would not use more list, just use a sorted list with a Comparator using the priority as a factor to put the process in the correct place.

Comment: @AxelH In the brief it states a 'multi-priority level queue' now theres not much online about this so my best guess was a queue for each priority. I also have a version that sorts based purely on priority but just for the entire process list

Comment: So you have a requirement but doesn't have the exact description. So it could be a simple FIFO based but with 3 distinct queue, first need to empty the HIGH then then the MEDIUM and the LOW.

Comment: Pretty much all it states is this "use a multi-priority level queues strategy to schedule processes and use the Shortest Job first strategy to schedule processes inside each queue."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into the `PriorityQueue` from java, is sorts itself if you add/remove a value with a comparator

Comment: Yes I was going to look into it but worried it might affect the whole code etc, at the moment it works fine when its just one whole process list but now I have made it into 3 lists im stuck

Comment: You can use one `PriorityQueue` for all the processes at once, there is a threadsafe version, just write a comparator that sorts the tasks correctly and if a thread is ideling poll the fist item or if the queue is empty let it wait

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a `java.util.PriorityQueue` and define a `Comparator`for your `Process` class (or let it implement `Comparable`). Then you simply add all your processes to it and the queue sorts them.

Comment: In the brief it states I should use multi priority level queues - assuming this is 3 queues for each prioritywhat my aim is, is to process all HIGH, then if HIGH empty process MILD etc

Comment: The comparator for the queue can handle multiple priority levels.